# Should there be author-only tags? (E.g. `newbie`)

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

This discussion is prompted by this question: [*Why is the 'newbie' tag not allowed?*](http://Meta.StackOverflow.Com/questions/60852/)

There are two reasons for not allowing a `newbie` tag:

1. [It is a meta-tag](http://Blog.StackOverflow.Com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).
2. It is often used in a pejorative way.

I'm interested in reason number 2. If a tag is disallowed *only* for the reason that it might be used in a pejorative way, would it make sense to allow authors to tag *their own* posts with it? At first glance, it seems to make sense.

[Note that in this *particular* case, the tag would still be disallowed for being a meta-tag. I'm only using `newbie` as an example here, I'm more interested in the general principle. But read on for a discussion on meta-ness.]

However: what would the list of such tags be? Specifically, would such tags necessarily be about the author and not the content of the question an thus automatically be [meta-tags](http://Blog.StackOverflow.Com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)?

Comment: I have to say, I find the view of "newbie" as being pejorative kind of interesting. Not that I don't understand it, certainly, but these days the people I see who would use it pejoratively are all illiterate and use renderings such as "n00b". Those using the term "newbie" aren't usually doing so in a particularly mean-spirited way.

Comment: @Nicholas Play counter-strike: this will change your mind ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We tag questions, not the skill level or character of the asker.

A tag only available for the asker, does not look like a good tag to describe the content of the question. So skip it!

Answer (score 7):

This has *nothing* to do with it being a derogatory term.  It is just a stone cold meta tag, belonging the 'beginner' class of tags.  It is utterly useless as a tag to filter questions that might be interesting:

- newbies can ask very interesting questions because they don't know the dogma.
- I'm a very experienced programmer but will always be a Perl newbie.  You don't have to talk slow to answer one of my Perl questions.
- 95% of all C# programmers are newbies when you use the Jon Skeet Measure.

It's a self-esteem tag.  I'm interested in the question, not what you think of yourself.

Comment: Based on this logic, there should be no Intro CS classes or Beginning Python Programming books or Learning Haskell videos or Starting with Vim sites.  As a hobbyist programmer, I found the beginner tag very helpful and have yet to find a way to find the same content as efficiently as before the tag was abolished.

Answer (score 2):

To me, a pejorative tag is always **subjective** (and thus a `meta-tag`) since you give your opinion.

I see this as a good reason for not allowing them.